# How to extract duplicate values in each column separately?

Tags: python, r, pandas, csv, duplicates

I want to extract only values with two or more occurrence in each column separately and write them in separate file with column header.

Example file: (actual csv file is 1.5 Gb, here including summary of it)
First row is the header row of each column

```
AO1,BO1,CO1,DO1,EO1,FO1
pep2,red2,ter3,typ3,ghl4,rtf5
ghp2,asd2,ghj3,typ3,ghj3,ert4
typ2,sdf2,rty3,ert4,asd2,sdf2
pep2,xcv2,bnm3,wer3,vbn3,wer2
dfg4,fgh3,uio2,wer3,ghj2,rtf5
dfg6,xcv4,dfg3,ret5,ytu2,rtf5
pep2,xcv4,ert1,dgf2,ert3,fgh3
okj2,xcv4,jkl3,ghr4,cvb3,rtf5
poi2,tyu2,iop3,cvb3,hjk5,rtf5
qwe2,wer2,iop3,typ3,ert3,cvb3
```

I have tried to write code in R and even Python panda but failed to get the result.

Expected outcome:

```
AO1 BO1 CO1 DO1 EO1 FO1
pep2    xcv4    iop3    typ3    ert3    rtf5
pep2    xcv4    iop3    typ3    ert3    rtf5
pep2    xcv4        typ3        rtf5
            wer3        rtf5
            wer3        rtf5
```

Comment: Hi, please add whatever relevant code you've written so far.

Comment: Could you describe how that input gets to that expected output... I'm not able to see any correlation between the two...

Comment: Do you want a separate file for each column? Also, do you really want all instances of the duplicates written to file?

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
from StringIO import StringIO

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO("""AO1,BO1,CO1,DO1,EO1,FO1
pep2,red2,ter3,typ3,ghl4,rtf5
ghp2,asd2,ghj3,typ3,ghj3,ert4
typ2,sdf2,rty3,ert4,asd2,sdf2
pep2,xcv2,bnm3,wer3,vbn3,wer2
dfg4,fgh3,uio2,wer3,ghj2,rtf5
dfg6,xcv4,dfg3,ret5,ytu2,rtf5
pep2,xcv4,ert1,dgf2,ert3,fgh3
okj2,xcv4,jkl3,ghr4,cvb3,rtf5
poi2,tyu2,iop3,cvb3,hjk5,rtf5
qwe2,wer2,iop3,typ3,ert3,cvb3"""))

d = {}

for col in df.columns:
    repeated_values =  df[col].value_counts()[df[col].value_counts() >= 2].index.tolist()
    cond = df[col].isin(repeated_values)
    d[col] = df[cond][col]

final = pd.concat(d, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df <- data.table::fread('AO1,BO1,CO1,DO1,EO1,FO1
pep2,red2,ter3,typ3,ghl4,rtf5
ghp2,asd2,ghj3,typ3,ghj3,ert4
typ2,sdf2,rty3,ert4,asd2,sdf2
pep2,xcv2,bnm3,wer3,vbn3,wer2
dfg4,fgh3,uio2,wer3,ghj2,rtf5
dfg6,xcv4,dfg3,ret5,ytu2,rtf5
pep2,xcv4,ert1,dgf2,ert3,fgh3
okj2,xcv4,jkl3,ghr4,cvb3,rtf5
poi2,tyu2,iop3,cvb3,hjk5,rtf5
qwe2,wer2,iop3,typ3,ert3,cvb3'
                  , data.table = FALSE)

lapply(df, function (x) x[duplicated(x) | duplicated(x, fromLast = T)])
```

You could write a csv directly in the lapply call as well